# BDD framework with python

Tags: python, testing, cucumber, bdd, gherkin

I need to write a test using cucumber for a course.

Scenario:

1. Login,
2. Select first item link,
3. Add item to the shopping cart,
4. Proceed shopping cart page,
5. Check the item on that list is correct,
6. Proceed to checkout,
7. Complete and Logout.

The point I don't understand is, do I need to open a feature file for each step and do I need to close and reopen the browser for each step? How should I do this? What kind of path should I follow?

(Note that I am a beginner and my English skills are limited, so I need a simple explanation.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should make a new file for each feature. For example, login.gherkin, upload.gherkin, logout.gherkin.

PS. Sorry, I didn't realize you said Python, but it's the same idea.

Each file should have a layout like this:

```
# Created by Mick Jagger at 1/13/2021
  @login
Feature: Login

  Scenario: Login to Website Homepage
    When Launch website
    Then Enter username and password
    And Log in
```

Then make the corresponding step file like this:

```
package glue;

import cucumber.api.java.en.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import java.util.List;

public class LoginSteps extends Driver {
    public String username = "username";
    public String password = "password";

    @When("Launch Website")
    public void launch_website() throws Throwable {
        driver.get("https://www.website.com/");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

    @Then("^Enter username and password$")
    public void enter_credentials() throws Throwable {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@aria-label='Phone number, username, or email']")).sendKeys(username);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@aria-label='Password']")).sendKeys(password);
    }

    @And("^Log in$")
    public void log_in() throws Throwable {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.tagName("button"));
        buttons.get(1).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.tagName("button")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        buttons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[@tabindex='0']"));
        buttons.get(1).click();
    }
}
```

If you're new to browser automation, I recommend learning the "Page Object Model Methodology". Also, I stopped using this annoying framework, it's supposed to make things easier but to me it just adds extra work.